# 座標の情報を取得するにはどうしたらいいですか？

Tags: swift, xcode, iphone, xcode7, swift2

すみません、swift及びプログラミング初心者です。
独学でスタンプカメラアプリの作成にチャレンジしています。

現在、ViewController.swiftというファイルとは別にStamp.swiftというファイルを用意しています。
Stamp.swiftには、下記のようなコードを書いています。

```
import UIKit

class Stamp: UIImageView {
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        self.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(self)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first!
        let dx = touch.locationInView(self.superview).x - touch.previousLocationInView(self.superview).x
        let dy = touch.locationInView(self.superview).y - touch.previousLocationInView(self.superview).y
        self.center = CGPointMake(self.center.x+dx, self.center.y+dy)
    }
```

Stamp.swiftでは、画面上で指を動かした時の最終的なx.y座標が取得できていると思います。
ViewController.swiftでは、画像を移動した際の最終的なx.y座標に画像の縮小率をかける
などをして、新たなx.y座標を求める必要があります。

Stamp.swiftで取得した、画像を移動した際の最終的なx.y座標をViewController.swiftで
使用したいのですがどのようなコーディングをすべきなのかご教示いただけますでしょうか。
加えまして、画面にスタンプ画像を沢山配置した場合、全てのスタンプ画像のx.y座標を一度に取得できるものなのでしょうか。
以上、よろしくおねがいいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

おそらく ViewController の中に 大量の Stamp(StampViewのほうが一般的な命名かも)がある設計だと思うので

```
protocol ViewDelegate {
    func viewMoved(x,y)
}
```

みたいなdelegate を作って、

```
class Stamp: UIImageView {
    var delegate:ViewDelegate!

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        delegate.viewMoved(self,x,y)  // delegate に通知
    }
    :
    :
}


class ViewController: SuperClass, ViewDelegate{

    func viewMoved(stamp, x,y){
        // Stamp が移動し終わったらここに処理が来る
    }   
}
```

という感じでしょうか。ViewController にすべてのStampインスタンス配列をもたせるといろいろと便利かもしれませんね。

Answer (score 0):

ViewControllerでどんな風にStampを管理しているのかがわからないので、subviewの中から該当するものを探して処理する方法を紹介します。

以下のような処理を、ViewControllerでStampを処理したい部分に書くことで対応できるかと思われます。

```
// subviewの中からStampのものを探す
for vi in view.subviews {
    if let stamp = vi as? Stamp {

        // 見つけたStampの値を使ってなにか処理
        print("center: \(stamp.center.x), \(stamp.center.y)")
    }
}
```

この他にも、tagを設定しておいてviewWithTag()を使う方法や、filter()を使う方法などが考えられます。